# How can one add 28 days to a date in java for android

Tags: java, android

I need to add 28 days to a Date - I have tried this:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date1 = df.parse("01/10/2012");
long week = 1000 * 60 * 24 * 7;
date1.setTime(date1.getTime() + week);
```

but I got an error on this line: `Date date1 = df.parse("01/10/2012");`

the error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.util.Date to java.sql.Date`

I also tried this:

```
Date Mydate = new Date(02,04,2012);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  
cal.setTime(Mydate);  
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 10); // add 10 days  
Mydate = (Date) cal.getTime();
```

but I got an error when trying to see the Mydate value.

Comment: *"I would like others to explain "*, Others would like to know the reason for this?

Comment: Could you add the error you're getting?

Comment: you need to tell us which errors you get

Comment: `but i got error on this line: Date date1 = df.parse("01/10/2012");` what is the error here? Post both stack traces

Comment: Are you sure that you have `import java.util.Date`, and *not* (for example) `import java.sql.Date`?

Comment: By the way, regardless of what `Date` class you're using, you'd have to write `new Date(2012,02,04)` -- though it's better to use `cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2012)` and so on to set the initial date, anyway.

Comment: @Gold see ruakh comment above, you seem to be mixing java.util.Date and java.sql.Date...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change this line:

```
import java.sql.Date;
```

to this:

```
import java.util.Date;
```

Once you've done that, I think the best approach is:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2012);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 3); // NOTE: 0 is January, 1 is February, etc.
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2);
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 10); // add 10 days
Date date = cal.getTime();
```

Comment: thanks for the help !!, how to change 'sat oct 13 13:15:44 GMT+00:00 2012'  to  '13/10/2012'

Comment: @Gold: You're welcome! As for getting the output `13/10/2012` -- I'd use `SimpleDateFormatter` for that.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.US);
    Date date1 = df.parse("01/10/2012");            
    System.out.println(date1);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date1);
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 28); // add 28 days  
    date1 = (Date) cal.getTime();
    System.out.println(date1);
}
```

Comment: *This works for me*, sure, but it may not (actually, most likely won't) work for him. `SimpleDateFormat` is locale sensitive. See my answer for how to set the locale explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Try code below:

```
Calendar MyDate= Calendar.getInstance();
long sum = MyDate.getTimeInMillis() + 2419200000; //28 days in milliseconds
MyDate.setTimeInMillis(sum);
```